# How heavy should a Chinese chef's knife be?

Tags: equipment, asian-cuisine, knife-skills

What weight should a Chinese chef's knife be and for what purpose?

- All around, i.e. one knife for most cooking
- Slicing
- Chopping vegetables
- Meat without bones
- Chicken or fish with bones

Chinese chef's knife is left-most in the picture below.

[image: Variety of chef's knife, Creative Commons, Wikimedia]

Comment: When you downvote a question please provide comments why you dislike a given question or how it could be improved.

Comment: What is a "Chinese chef's knife"? How does it look like? Any pictures? Do they have a range of knife types or just one type of knives?

Comment: China is a VERY big country, what part of China are you referring too?

Comment: Cleaver is probably a better term to use? "Chinese chef's knife" is pretty ambiguous, you should be more specific about the type of knife.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitchen_knife#Chinese_chef.27s_knife it does look like cleaver, however western cleaver is used only for meat and bones work, while Chinese/Asian chef's knife (rectangular) is a multipurpose tool, for slicing and dicing vegetables and light meat work. Real butchery is done with a dedicated tool

Comment: For example, this shop offers weight range from 306 to 795g, the heaviest is recommended for meat with bones. While this gives me a range, I'd like `seasoned` advice from fellow cooks. http://www.japanesechefsknife.com/ChineseCleaver.html if it matters, I'm an able-bodied Northern European chap.

Comment: @TFD and BlessedGeek, a Chinese knife is a term in the kitchen which has long superseded its literal meaning of just any knife produced somewhere in China. It is a type of knife which originated somewhere in China, but is now universal.

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73231/what-do-the-numbers-used-to-differentiate-chinese-slicer-knives-mean is probably related...

Answer (score 2):

A chinese style chef's knife, also known as the *cai dow*, or [vegetable cleaver](http://www.cooksillustrated.com/equipment_reviews/1336-vegetable-cleavers)(trial subscription required, but an excellent article), is superficially similar to a western cleaver. The cleaver is typically a very robust blade, thick and weighty, meant for separating meat at the joint, splitting ribs and chops, and other tasks that require a lot of weight and a stiff blade.

The chinese chef's knife will be much thinner and lighter, comparable to a western chef's knife or Japanese nakiri. The broad face is for scooping up ingredients from the cutting board and controllability rather than mass and strength. From a [brief blog entry](http://www.thekitchn.com/the-only-knife-you-need-the-mu-127724) from Kitchn on the knife -

> In her book Shark’s Fin and Sichuan Pepper: A Sweet-Sour Memoir of
>   Eating in China, Fuchsia Dunlop explains, “The Chinese cleaver is not
>   a butcher’s knife...The everyday cleaver, the cai dao or vegetable
>   knife, is unexpectedly light and dexterous, as suitable for slicing a
>   small shallot as a great hunk of meat, and used by everyone from the
>   most macho chef to the frailest old lady.”

Comment: Good solid answer, but how much should this knife weigh? If you use one, how much does it weigh?

Comment: @qarma - It will vary from one model to another, depending on the steel, the handle type, and the construction. In my experience, it will be comparable to a german-style chef's knife: a little heavier than a french style knife or santoku due to its size, much less heavy than a meat cleaver. Frustratingly, manufacturers don't seem to list the weight of their knives in their product specifications.

Comment: in many parts of China the main knife is much heavier than a typical western chef knife, and much larger

Answer (score 1):

Many actual Chinese cooks use very large cleavers which are heavier than a typical western chefs knife

These are used for everything, meat, veges, noodles, small things, large things, even when doing tricky stuff

Hot pot butchers (usually working on the street outside a restaurant) use very large and slightly curved cleavers to make thin slices of lamb (mutton!), these are about 500 mm long, and look very heavy, but make short work of the animal

All this seems to be mainly cultural, e.g. when you check out some of the fancier restaurants around Shanghai, you will see some of the chefs using typical western chefs knives :-)

[image: Chinese knife going sideways]
[image: Typical Chinese knife usage]

Answer (score 0):

Weight and thickness with depend on what you are cutting and personal preference.  Many Chinese cleavers are marked with a numbering system, which depends on the manufacturer. A very light one is used for light jobs (mostly vegetables), and medium for all purpose jobs (vegetables and boneless meats) , and the heavy ones for bones just as a Western cleavers.

But in most cases it is going to weigh more than a typical western chef's knife.  The typical Chinese cleaver is going to feel much more blade heavy.  So getting your grip as close to the blade is going to give you more control and less fatigue, until you get used to the feel of the cleaver. The blade heavy balance helps you use the cleaver's weight to your advantage.  Basically just lift the blade and let the weight cut the food, with just a bit of downforce and guidance on your part.

Comment: Can you provide some example weights, as in grams or ounces?